# Ethereum Wallet suddenly cant find peers anymore

Tags: go-ethereum, wallets, synchronization, network

I have a problem with my Ethereum Wallet. It was fully synchronized previously and constantly resynched while it was open and also after several shutdowns of the machine. Now, it suddenly stopped working and cant seem to find any peers. 
The strange thing is, it says its connecting to X peers everytime (in the little blue start screen) but then just cant download anything. When I open the application it says `peers(no number)|880 blocks left|0%`. That never changes. Only when I close and restart the application the number of blocks left jumps up. The application is responsive and all data (account, contracts) are still there.
This started while I was actually using it. I had just created a contract on the main network and send a transaction to it. Both those transactions went through normally. Right after I send another transaction to this contract and right then it stopped synchronizing.

- Its running on Linux Peppermint in a VM hosted with Virtualbox. I have restarted both the linux vm and the windows host. The Linux has internet, I am using a browser on it to post this question. The problem has persisted over several hours now.
- I have read somewhere that system time is an issue. I am new to Linux but I am fairly sure that the system time is synchronized. To check I have set the system time to "manual" and entered a random time. Saved, closed, and reopened, set it to automatic again and it automatically set the correct time. I am assuming this time must have come from some time server.
- Geth is not running in another instance. I have checked with both `ps` and `killall`.
- I have tried starting `geth` through the terminal. It says **two** different things:

  > Peer de471bccee3d0422 [eth/63]: timed out DAO fork-check, dropping

  which I googled and found to be just a peer using incompatible software, and:

  > converting 1600000 canonical numbers...

  Increasing the number in steps of 100000. There were a few of both these messages but nothing else after like half an hour.

At this point, I have no clue what the problem is or what else I could do to figure it out. What can I do to get it working again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am having trouble too. I think it may be due to a geth bug:

https://blog.ethereum.org/2016/09/18/security-alert-geth-nodes-crash-due-memory-bug/

I think we may need to wait for a new version of geth / mist wallet to be released?

Edit: I ran mist wallet on windows, while trying to sync beyond block 2283415, and watched the geth process start eating memory, past 13GB, until the geth process just dies.

Comment: Yes, thats it! Geth is stuck on exactly that block. But how do I update it? Checking for updates for the Ethereum Wallets doesnt help, it says I am using the newest version already

Comment: Unfortunately at this point you need to get the new geth source compiled, and overwrite your mist geth executable I believe. https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/releases/tag/v1.4.12

Comment: Updated Mist: https://github.com/ethereum/mist/releases/tag/0.8.3

Comment: Its still not working! I replaced my ethereum wallet with new release 1.4.12 and it still has the exact same problem. I also tried parity(which was supposed to be unaffected) and it too gets stuck at block 2283415...

Comment: You may need to delete your blockchain data and resync from scratch? I will try this on my windows install later and post back.

Comment: Geth is still using the old blockchain data, but parity has already started from scratch... Why is it not working either?

Comment: I installed mist wallet 0.8.3 on windows, and after a lot of waiting (and ~2.4GB memory footprint), it finally synced the blockchain and I could get into the wallet. After this episode, I have evaluated www.myetherwallet.com, and will be using that as a wallet using the mist keystores going forward. Good luck!

Comment: same with Parity, after like two hours it finally got past 2283415. Web wallets are no option for me. I use Ethereum, because I am working on a smart contract project, I dont think web wallets allow contract creation at this point.

Comment: https://www.myetherwallet.com/#deploy-contract

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Do I need to update Mist to 0.8.3, will this solve the problem?